# How to git rebase -i edit and see past commits changes

Tags: git, commit, rebase

Usually I'm editing old commits with `git rebase -i HEAD~<number of commits I added>` put `edit` on the commits I want to edit, make the change, adding files and `git rebase --continue`.

Is there a way to edit commits with rebase but to see the past commit changes? it will be much easier to spot the places I want to fix there, VScode mark the lines for me.

example:
let's say I have committed `commitA`, `commitB`, `commitC` (HEAD at commitC).
now I would like to edit commitA. I'm `git rebase -i HEAD~3` and put `edit` on commitA. now I'm in the middle of my rebase but I want `commitA`
changes to appear as changes, the situation is making me write my fix when `commitA` changes are already committed.

if there is an alternative way of fixing past commit and having that commit changes as `staged` that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have in mind here.  What _don't_ you see that you wish you did see?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added an example, is my question clearer now?

Answer (score 7):

o.k seems it's easier than I thought! just follow those steps:
let's say I want to edit 5 commits back:

1. `git rebase -i HEAD~5`
2. change pick to edit on the commits you want to edit.
3. your interactive rebase will start, if you want to see current commit changes type `git reset HEAD~1` since the commit already there, were just resetting it.
4. make your changes.
5. `git add <files of your change and past commit files>` or just `git add -u` to add all tracked files.
6. `git commit`
7. `git rebase --continue`

happy gitting :)

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the commit message? I currently copy the commit message into an editor and paste it back when committing, and feel incredibly stupid about it...

Comment: I found it myself: `git commit --reuse-message=ORIG_HEAD` will use the commit message from the commit prior to `git reset HEAD~1`. If you need to change something in that message do a `git commit --amend` after.