# How to git rebase -i edit and restore all the change of that commit

Tags: git

In the question [How to git rebase -i edit and see past commits changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64801132/how-to-git-rebase-i-edit-and-see-past-commits-changes) the author gave a solution with using `git reset`. However, that solution loss the commit message of the commit edited. Is there any way to edit a specific commit (not the latest one) and restore all the changes when editing?

For example, here is the command I executed.

```sh
user$ ~/test_git(main○)» touch a
user$ ~/test_git(main⚡)» git add -A                                                                                                              1 ↵
user$ ~/test_git(main⚡)» git commit -m "a"
[main (root-commit) 50fc2a7] a
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
user$ ~/test_git(main○)» touch b
user$ ~/test_git(main⚡)» git add -A
user$ ~/test_git(main⚡)» git commit -m "b"
[main ec313ba] b
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 b
user$ ~/test_git(main○)» git rebase HEAD~1 -i

> edit ec313ba b

Stopped at ec313ba...  b
You can amend the commit now, with

  git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

  git rebase --continue
```

What I actually get from `git status`

```sh
user$ ~/test_git(ec313ba○)» git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto 50fc2a7
Last command done (1 command done):
   edit ec313ba b
No commands remaining.
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'main' on '50fc2a7'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

What I want to get

```sh
user$ ~/test_git(50fc2a7⚡)» git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto 50fc2a7
Last command done (1 command done):
   edit ec313ba b
No commands remaining.
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'main' on '50fc2a7'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   b
```

I want the change of the commit I edited to become the `Changes to be committed` and also to keep the message.

Comment: What do you mean by "restore all the changes"?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you do `git rebase -i <a-point-in-the-history>`, and then mark required commits with `edit`, you actually get the commit message and all other attributes. This happens because a commit selected for editing is first applied (cherry-picked over a selected HEAD) and then `git` gives you a chance to *amend* it. So you can make all necessary changes and then use `git add`/`git commit --amend` to make amendments to the commit. The latter command `git commit --amend` lets you to preserve commit message and other commit attributes. You may also override some attributes with `--author`, `--date` and `--reuse-message=<commit>` options.

In order to emulate the requested "new commit" behavior, when git stops on a particular commit for amending, one could reset `HEAD` to a previous commit, while retaining working tree and index intact with `git reset --soft HEAD^`:

```
<git applies the commit marked `edit` and pauses rebasing> (0)
$ git reset --soft HEAD^      (1)
<edit>                        (2)
$ git commit -a -c ORIG_HEAD  (3)
```

However, I believe that `git commit --amend` and corresponding features of IDEs and other GUI tools for GIT are way more clean way to achieve the same result.

Comment: This steps will not make the changes of the commit marked `edit` showed in the `Changes to be committed` section. I want to see the change with `git diff` which is used by my editor.

Comment: you still can see the changes made in a commit. Virtually every editor with a decent Git support has an option to amend a last commit ("amend last commit" checkbox in `Git Gui` tool, "Amend" checkbox in IntelliJ Idea and so on). So, chances are, you already can view the changes in the commit marked `edit` during `git rebase`, just click on the checkbox.

However you can make it even more similar to what you want. If you make `git reset --soft HEAD^` just after `git rebase -i` has been paused for amending, you will likely get exactly what you want.

Comment: How can I reuse the original commit message atfer invoking `git reset --soft HEAD^`? Do I can only get the message with `git reflog`?